# how to add page-map.xml in Sigil?

Tags: epub

I understand that ePub2 standard does not include page numbers, but ADE added a non-standard extension which may or may not work on an actual reader. I would like to try to use them, but I found a problem. 
[MobileRead Wiki](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Adobe_Digital_Editions#Page-map) says to add in content.opf a reference to an xml file, usually called page-map.xml. Sigil, as of version 0.9.6, recognizes and updates an existing page-map.xml, but I don't know where to put it (and how to put it in, short of renaming the file in .zip and adding it with brute force).

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the **Misc** folder icon and select **Add Existing Files...**
(You'll also have to manually update the .opf file.)

BTW, Sigil won't automatically update this file.

Comment: Ah, this was the trouble! I must edit it externally and adding it at the end... I thought that even if Sigil would not automaticall update the file I could have edited it, but file-->add did not allowed me to create a "generic" file.